Clarification on Editable Properties and Package Upgrade Behavior
I have a question regarding editable properties after package promotion or installation, specifically for scenarios where both the subscriber and the package developer can edit component properties.
Scenario:
Both Subscriber and Package Developer Can Edit:

Both the subscriber and package developer can edit component properties. However, developer changes are only applied to new subscriber installs. This prevents a package upgrade from overwriting changes made by the subscriber. For example, the help text on a custom field and the page layout of a custom object are editable by both the subscriber and package developer. Subscribers can modify the page layout or help text and trust that their changes won’t be overwritten by future package upgrades.

Question:
If a metadata component has not been modified by the subscriber, can the upgrade package update its value? Or are updates only applied to new installs?
Example:
I have an external credential initially installed in Org A and Org B. I would like to upgrade theDescription variable of this external credential (refer to documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_external_credential). Both Package Developer and Subscriber Can Edit Description variable

In Org A, the system admin has already changed the Description value to their own.
In Org B, the Description value remains as default.
When upgrading the package, will the new Description value be updated only in Org B (where it has not been modified) or will it not be updated in both Orgs A and B?

Thank you guys for your assistance in clarifying this behavior.


However, developer changes are only applied to new subscriber installs.

Properties that are both subscriber- and developer-editable will be set just once on the initial install. This is an absolute rule without exception. Salesforce doesn't "remember" if a managed component has been edited by the subscriber, and so won't attempt to change the value during an upgrade. For this reason, if you have components that fall under this definition, you'll have to create post-upgrade instructions for your subscribers to follow, or if applicable, use an InstallHandler script to migrate protected component data.

How about translation for custom object/field and picklist value? We encounter many issue about translation during upgrade these metadata?
